# Run workflow over all entities to copy data from one field to another

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm in a situation where i need to add a default value "blank" to my "Two Options" field. Since I cannot set a default value of "null" to an already created Two Options field, I though of creating a new custom field of type "Option Set" and add the same two options Yes/No in addition to setting the Default value to Unassigned.

I need to create a workflow that copies the old values choices into the new field. I understand that I can't simple equate the values of two fields of different type but I'm going to do that with Check conditions to set the new field value corresponding to the old field value.

I'm not sure how to run this workflow against all the existing records in my CRM online with no codes. Is that possible ?

Comment: this kind of questions don't belong to stackoverflow, next time try msdn forums or community dynamics forums. check this tool http://zero2ten.com/ms-dynamics-crm-2011-bulk-workflow-execution-tool/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using code or custom tools your best options are:

1. Do an advanced find, select all the records in the view and run the workflow - this will run the workflow against every record. You can view up to 250 records at a time (check personal settings to change this) so this might work for you.
2. Export all the data to Excel, make the change in Excel in bulk. Reimport the data. This way you don't need workflow at all.